# How to implement multi form with one submit button in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to web development and ruby on rails and I'm copying other websites for practice.

Right now I'm trying to make a copy of BiggerPockets "rehab estimator tool", which have several features i would like to implement in my own end project.

I'm not sure how to structure the project and would like some feedback on my ideas.

1. Model: I was thinking about generating a model "rehabJob" and "rehabReport", making rehabJob correspond to every line (ex. roof replacement, totalOnly, price: 2000 USD) and rehabReport begin a model containing a reportTitle and other rehabJobs (ex roof replacement, paint jobs, new flooring etc.)
2. How would I submit a form with multiple rehabJob models, with only 1 submit button
3. Ideas of how to implement the "delete/adding" of new lines (rehabJobs)

The link for the tool: https://www.biggerpockets.com/rehab-estimator/new

Image of biggerpockets rehab estimator tool:

[image: Screenshot 1]

Comment: In your shoes I'd take a look at the coccoon gem which provides easy tools for adding / removing nested records.  They give easy instructions on usage at their site.  https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

Comment: @SteveTurczyn You should put that as an answer. That, to me, is the best solution. I would also add wicked_wizard gem IF you need multiple steps.https://github.com/zombocom/wicked

Comment: Thanks, @Int'lManOfCodingMystery I hadn't come across the Wiicked gem before, looks interesting.

Answer (score 2):

In your shoes I'd take a look at the `coccoon` gem which provides easy tools for adding / removing nested records. They give easy instructions on usage at their site. https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon